# Проблема SSL Android

Tags: java, android, веб-программирование, ssl, сетевое-программирование

У меня есть проблема. Я настроил на сервере ларавел на порту 8080. Работает по https. Сертификатом вроде все в порядке. При попытке запроса через андроид приложения выводит исключение

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)
```

Исключение по данному серверу выводит как retrofit так и glide(думаю и другие библиотеки). При настройке retrofit так чтобы он не проверял сертификаты все работает. При запросе через postman все работает исправно. В чем может заключаться проблема. Просьба не посылать меня к бэкэндеру и сетевеку поскольку я сам и выполняю их работу)

Comment: Почему вы решили, что с сертификатом все в порядке? Как проверяли его (работа postman не считается)? Откуда сертификат вообще взялся?

Comment: @andreymal сертификат стоял еще до меня. Проблем с ним не возникало. Проверил еще через один сервис. Сервис проверяет сертификат и приват ключ на соответствие. Там тоже вроде все окей

Comment: @andreymal вы можете предложить однозначный способ проверки сертификата?

Comment: @FarizMamedow, а на каком девайсе тестируете? С https есть проблемы на 4.4. Их можно костылём вылечить, если на 5+ нормально работает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб api Q. Одна из последних можно считать

Comment: Попробуйте отсюда ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28785936/3212712

Comment: Вопрос был не за API а устройство на котором вы тестируете, До API21 есть проблемы с поддержкой SSL1.2, лечится костылями, свыше всё гуд работает.